# How to get Id field in laravel store function using query builder?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to do a create function in laravel crud controller and I need to get the id of categories to store a new subcategory.
In my categories table on mysql db I have the name field and a father id that represent the father category, I'm making a function to create new subcategories but i'm not able to retrieve the father id

My controller:

```
  {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
//User insert the name of the father category
            'category' => 'exists:categories,name'
        ]);

        $category = new Category();

//I try to extract id from table
        $father_id = Category::where('name', '=', $request->input('category'))->value('id');

        $category->name = $request->input('name');
        $category->father_id = $father_id;

        $category->save();
       // return $father_id;
         return redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('success', 'category added successfully');
    }
```

when I try to return 'father_id' variable is empty

Comment: it just means that your query criteria `where('name', '=', $request->input('category'))` returned nothing. What do you need help with? what is not clear here?

Comment: I suggest using `parent` instead of `father` - it is the industry standard.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build your form using either Categories selection with category's id as value.

This will eliminate possibility your user input a random category name.
And at the same time your problem will be solved because you will get category Id directly from user input / submitted data.

Example

```
<select name="category_id">
  <option value="0">No parent category</option>
  <option value="1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2</option>
  ....
</select>
```

And inside your controller

```
{
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'category_id' => 'integer|exists:categories,id'
        ]);

        // optional here you can add extra checker if combination already exists.

        // lets create users's new Category
        $category = Category::create([
            'name' => $validated['name'],
            'father_id' => $validated['category_id'],
        ]);

        return redirect()
            ->route('categories.index')
            ->with('success', 'New category is added successfully');
    }
```

Note: there might be error using current validation if category_id is 0